# How do I create an MS Outlook 2010 rule that moves all messages received on a specific day of the week?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

How do I create an MS Outlook 2010 rule that moves all messages received on a specific day of the week?

For example: If I receive an email on a Saturday, it should be automatically moved to a folder called "Saturday".

Comment: What have you researched or tried so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

THIS IS FOR A SPECIFIC DATE:
In the HOME tab click on rules>create rules, then advanced options. Then check "received in a specific date span" and then click on the blue link in the "step 2" box. Check the box "after" and select Friday and check the box "before" and check Sunday. Then click next and choose what you want to do with the emails that are received after Friday but before Sunday (which are the Saturday emails).

THIS IS FOR A DAY OF THE WEEK ALWAYS RECURRING:
Choose the rule "with specific words in the message header" then type the abbreviation for the day of the week you want (Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun). If you want emails on Thursdays moved then type "Thu" click "add" and then click next and have those emails move to the Thursday folder.

Comment: That is for specific dates, not specific days of the week. Can that be modified to be recurring?

Comment: Good point. I think I figured it out though! Choose the rule "with specific words in the message header" then type the abbreviation for the day of the week you want. If you want emails on Thursdays moved then type "Thu" and click next and have those emails move to the Thursday folder.

Comment: Thanks! Gotta make sure you don't use this approach to **EXCLUDE** emails on certain days of the week, though, because a day's sequence of letters can appear in the header for reasons other than day of the week (e.g., "Mon" would appear in the word "Money").

Comment: And when using it to include emails, for that reason some emails may slip through from other days if your day of week's letters appear in some other word in the header.

Comment: I use `; Mon,` which is less likely to appear anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be extremely certain that your rule is correct, you have to take example subsets of the message headers to make sure it will work. Even `; Mon,` was not good enough for my case. There were multiple instances of that pattern with different days, so it didn't work for me. For me the best pattern was: `>; Mon,`.

For 2016 (I imagine it's similar for 2010), you can find our the message headers (Internet headers) by opening the email with a double click, clicking File > (Info tab) > Properties > Internet headers. Copy it out into a text editor and search for instances of `;` and look for what is before the semi-colon so you can do a pattern that works in 100% of the cases.

Comment: I also found (I guess as you suggest it depends on versions etc.) That there is a specific --> Date: Mon, <-- or Tue or whatever in the header that worked for me. Thanks for this suggestion.